# custom categoryattribute for control shadowed property

Tags: vb.net, propertygrid

I made a custom CategoryAttribute in order to localize properties of custom controls.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)> _
Public Class LocalisableCategoryAttribute
   Inherits CategoryAttribute

   Public Sub New(ByVal resourceName As String)
      MyBase.New(resourceName)
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Function GetLocalizedString(value As String) As String
      Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(value)
   End Function
End Class
```

My custom controls have both brand new properties with this attribute but I also shadowed some of the "basic" properties (such as the Size and Location) in order to give them this attribute.

```
  <LocalisableCategory("Category_Apparence")> _
  Public Shadows Property Size As Size
     Get
        Return MyBase.Size
     End Get
     Set(value As Size)
        MyBase.Size = value
     End Set
  End Property
```

The big problem is that at runtime, sometimes the new "Apparence" category will show up and sometimes the old "Layout" one will.  Only shadowed properties have this odd behavior.  It's totally random.  It's not a compile thing either.  You can launch the .exe twice in a row and the property grid won't show the same result.  Sometimes it will be put under its old category, sometimes the new localized one.

I am completely at a loss with this since it's so random.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)> _
Public Class LocalisableCategoryAttribute
   Inherits CategoryAttribute

Private resourceKey As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal resourceName As String)
      resourceKey = resourceName
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Function GetLocalizedString(value As String) As String
      Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceKey)
   End Function
End Class
```